# show button only if following div tag has some value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I have following html code - which displays a button and user clicks on it - it display
some text below.

```
<div>
 <button class="btn-default btn-primary show-answer-button">Show</button>
 <div class="answer"></div>
 </div>
```

But sometimes, when user clicks the button, there is no text . (so it displays nothing).
I would like to display this button only when the "answer" has some text. How to achieve this ?

I tried following (adding a id='answer-part' and insert a line at js file) but it didn't work:

```
 <div id="answer-part">
 <button class="btn-default btn-primary show-answer-button">Show</button>
 <div class="answer"></div>
 </div>
```

and add this at .js file

```
$('.answer-part:empty').hide();
```

Comment: Thank you for all the answers and  suggestions. After posting here, I found out the div tag 'answer' was embedded inside a JSON object. So will mark the one which helped me to debug further. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.answer:empty').hide().prev('button').hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the length property and contents() together:

```
$('button.btn-default.btn-primary.show-answer-button').click(function () {
    if ($(this).next().contents().length) $(this).next().show()
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ckmnznxn/1)**

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.show-answer-button')[$('.answer').text() ? "show":"hide"]();
```